# Is it possible to add a CiviCRM API to the Webform CiviCRM integration module and how would I do that?

Tags: webforms, civicrm

If I have created a specific CiviCRM API entity/action for a project, can I then add that API to the Webform CiviCRM integration module so that I can use the API in the Webform? And how would I do that?

Comment: Purely out of interest, has something changed in the CiviCRM website/docs recently to point people here to ask questions? We welcome them, of course, I was just wondering why we seem to have had an influx of them in the last week or so :)

Comment: I think the [site proposal for CiviCRM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2) has generated a lot of interest in SE among the Civi community.

Comment: You might want to put a few more specifics in your question about what API you want to add, and how you want to use it in the webform (since there are a lot of APIs and a lot of ways in which they could be used!)

Answer (score 3):

I found this old link for plans to add arbitrary api calls to the module, but it doesn't appear to have ever been implemented:
http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=22304.0

But it appears that I could use hook _webform_submission_presave to execute the api call when the webform is submitted.